# How should popular, yet problematic users be dealt with?

Tags: problem-users

Sometimes, a user can come along who is popular with the community in general, yet causes headaches for moderators. This can be in the form of pushing boundaries, leading uprisings against a moderator or the moderation team at large, or encouraging rifts in the community, or fights between users.

Such users often employ powerful social dynamics (such as an in-crowd) to disrupt and derail communities. How can users like this be dealt with in a way that does not cause further drama?